# How do I multiply arrays to output multiple arrays and not multiplied values?

Tags: python, arrays, list

I'm trying to put multiple of the same array into another array for a `random.choice()` function, to increase the chance that a specific array is more likely to be chosen, but none of the methods I tried seemed to produce the desired output

I've already tried multiplying the arrays or adding them together.

what I've tried:

```py
# multiplying the arrays
finalArray = [
    3 * [0, "You lost!"],
    5 * [1, "You won!"]
]

# adding them together
finalArray = [
    3 * [0, "You lost!"] +
    5 * [1, "You won!"]
]
```

I expected `finalArray` to be one array containing 8 sub-arrays, three losing scenarios and five winning, but the output is either two sub-arrays or one respectively.

I know that for-loops can be used to append to `finalArray` for each iteration, but I'd rather keep my code short.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're multiplying array it will produce array with N copies of elements you've multiplied. If you'll multiply array where elements are subarrays it will do what you want.

**Code:**

```
finalArray = 3 * [[0, "You lost!"]] + 5 * [[1, "You won!"]]
```

**Output:**

```
[[0, 'You lost!'], [0, 'You lost!'], [0, 'You lost!'], [1, 'You won!'], [1, 'You won!'], [1, 'You won!'], [1, 'You won!'], [1, 'You won!']]
```